# Injection in Repository

Tags: laravel, repository-pattern, laravel-5, laravel-ioc

I found many questions about my problem and tried (I think) all the solutions, but I can not make it work. I'm overlooking something very easy, probably.

I'm using Laravel 5. I try to implement a repository-pattern.
I have an Eloquent model '\Notos\Kind'.

Then I have this interface:

```
namespace Notos\Contracts;

interface Kind
{
    public function findByName($name);
}
```

My Repository looks like this:

```
namespace Notos\Repository;


use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Notos\Contracts\Kind as KindContract;

class Kind implements KindContract
{
    protected $kind;

    public function __construct(Model $kind)
    {
        $this->kind = $kind;
    }

    public function findByName($name)
    {
        return $this->kind->firstOrCreate(array('name' => $name));
    }
}
```

My ServiceProvider:

```
namespace Notos\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Notos\Kind;
use Notos\Repository\Kind as KindRepository;


class RepoServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{

    /**
     * Register the service provider.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind('Notos\Contracts\Kind', function ($app) {
            return new KindRepository(new Kind);
        });
    }
}
```

And my controller that uses the repository:

```
namespace Notos\Http\Controllers;

use Notos\Repository\Kind as KindRepository;

class KindController extends Controller
{
    protected $kind;

    public function __construct(KindRepository $kind)
    {
        $this->kind = $kind;
    }

    public function find($name)
    {
        return $this->kind->findByName($name);
    }
}
```

This provider is registered in config/app.php

When I try to execute the KindController@find I get this error:

```
BindingResolutionException in Container.php line 785:
Target [Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model] is not instantiable.
```

I can't find what I'm doing wrong. 
It works perfect if I change __construct(Model $kind) to __construct(Kind $kind).

Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing, I would advice you to add to your class names the function so for example instead of `Kind` for repository use `KindRepository`, the same for contract. Otherwise you will have 3 kinds classes (of course in different namespaces) but it will be hard to analyse the code.

The problem here is that in your `KindController` you try to inject `KindRepository` directly but in constructor you use `Model`. It won't work because `Model` is only abstract class. What you should do to make it work?

In the code:

```
$this->app->bind('Notos\Contracts\Kind', function ($app) {
            return new KindRepository(new Kind);
        });
```

you told Laravel that when you will use `Notos\Contracts\Kind` it should create `KindRepository` for you with `Kind` in constructor - look you told here about Contract, not about repository itself.

So to make it work, you should use in your controller not your repository, but your contract.

Instead of line:

```
use Notos\Repository\Kind as KindRepository;
```

you should write:

```
use Notos\Contracts\Kind as KindRepository;
```

and it should work now.